# Буква Й после согласных

Tags: орфография

В ПАСЕ написано: "После согласных буква **й** не пишется [(см. § 27 — 28)](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp27.php)
".

Однако в РОС РАН (Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин. © Электронная версия, «ГРАМОТА.РУ», 2001–2007) есть слова:
**безйодовый, межйеменский.**

Вопрос: Как следовало бы писать эти слова, ориентируясь на правило?
См.: по ссылке выше. Но ни одно слово, которое там представлено, не начинается на **й.**

Comment: Про правило ничего не скажу, но метка «оргография» мне понравилась :)

Comment: У Вас ссылка неправильная. Должна быть на [§ 26](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=22).

Comment: Ссылка правильна.

Comment: *В ПАСЕ  написано* - ну мало ли, что пишут в Парламентской ассамблее Совета Европы. ))))  "Оргография" рулит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> После согласных буква й не пишется (см. § 27 — 28).

.

**Серж,** эта неточность в ПАС была замечена сразу же после его выхода в свет в 2007 году (см. обсуждение на [**ГРАМОТЕ.РУ**](http://forum.gramota.ru/forum/read.php?f=14&i=12173&t=12167)).

К сожалению,  в уже выпущенных книгах трудно что-либо исправить. Погрешность эта была устранена в других справочниках и словарях, выпущенных авторами ПАС впоследствии.

Так, в книге ***Бешенковой Е. В.*** и ***Ивановой О. Е.*** (Ольга Евгеньевна Иванова  — одна из авторов ПАС, одна из авторов *"Русского орфографического словаря"*, ответственный редактор  — наряду с *Лопатиным*  — четвёртого издания этого словаря) ***"Правила русской орфографии с комментариями"*** (2012) фраза *"после согласных буква **й** не пишется"* была убрана, само же правило о ***й*** после приставки на согласный было сформулировано так:

> **§ 3. Передача звука [j]**
>
> <...>
>
> **3. П р а в и л о.** Сочетание звуков «[j] + гласный» после приставки на согласный передается сочетанием букв ***«ъ + е, ё, ю, я»***, если
>   корень начинается на йотированную букву, напр.: *разъехаться, разъём,
>   предъюбилейный, межъядерный, разъяренный, дизъюнкция, субъект, объект,
>   адъютант, адъюнкт, интеръекция, трансъевропейский.*
>
> **П р и м е ч а н и е.** Под формулировку не подпадают корни, начинающиеся на буквосочетание «й + гласная», в которых буква ***ъ,***
>   соответственно, не ставится, напр.: ***безйотовый, безйодовый.***

Так же изложено это правило и в вышедшем в 2015 году *"Объяснительном русском орфографическом словаре-справочнике"* (авторы  — Бешенкова Е. В., Иванова О. Е., Чельцова Л. К.).

Answer (score 2):

**У Лопатина в § 26** рассматриваются особенности употребления буквы  Й.

Как известно, звук   [j] («йот»)  может обозначаться **двумя способами**: буквой Й  или гласными буквами Я, Ё, Ю, Е, обозначающими  сочетание звуков [j] + гласный.

Буква Й пишется **в позиции**  **гласный** + [j] на конце слова или **гласный** + [j] + согласный (май,  майка), в остальных случаях используются буквы Я, Ё, Ю, Я. Если же перед [j] находится **согласный** звук, то применяются разделительные знаки Ь и Ъ совместно с буквами Я, Ё, Ю, Е.

**Это основные правила,  именно к ним относится замечание  Лопатина**: « После согласных буква й не пишется **(см. § 27 — 28)».**  Это ссылка на   параграфы, в которых рассматриваются правила употребления **разделительных** знаков в позиции **согласный** + [j] перед буквами Я, Ё, Ю, Е.

Но вот встретился **частный вариант**: редкие слова  йод, Йемен,  да еще производные от них безйодовый, межйеменский. И как их писать?  У нас только два способа**:  (1) буква Й или (2) разделительный Ъ и буквы Ё и Е . **Однозначно выбираем способ** (1),  для этого  частного случая не нужно правил, и этот вариант у Лопатина просто не рассматривается.

Comment: Спасибо,Sibylla. И все же, как мне кажется, Лопатин не последователен. В правилах одно,  в РОС РАН. Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин. © Электронная версия, «ГРАМОТА.РУ», именно такой вариант: "безйодовый".  Даже с МГУ последовало много замечаний. [Н. Николенкова. Орфографические словари русского языка сегодня и их соответствие действующим правилам русского языка](http://gramma.ru/KOL/?id=1.38)

Comment: Наверное, быть последовательным не так просто.  Новое время ставит более сложные задачи, а решать их становится труднее (конкуренция школ, нехватка кадров, недостаточное финансирование и т.д.).

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, что вообще хочет спросить автор, давая ссылки в никуда, подобные метки, и адресуясь не иначе как в Совет Европы.

Скорее всего просто непонимание смысла сказанного Лопатиным (возможно речь не шла о написании на морфемных швах - проверить не могу ибо правильных ссылок нет). Но даже если у Лопатина есть противоречие, то руководствоваться надо словарём как изданием непосредственно посвященном практической орфографии.

Т.е. написание **"безйодовый", "межйеменский"** следует признать правильным и не заморачиваться по поводу каких-то правил. Тем более, что и причин сомневаться в таком написании нет.

Comment: При всей неряшливости автора можно предположить, что правилом он называет наблюдение Лопатина относительно того, что после согласных Й якобы не встречается. Ну а ссылка - это либо ляп самого Лопатина, либо верстальщика. Ляп этот правда умножен Сержем, но понять можно с помощью Sasha. У Сержа это цитата из § 26. Там Лопатин по какому-то недоразумению ссылается на § 27, где ничего подобного не говорится. Ну а Серж эту ошибку просто скопипастил. Как-то так.

Comment: *и ни заморачиваться* - оргография?

Comment: Что непонятного?! В самом низу п.26. написано: "После согласных буква й не пишется". И дана ссылка на п.27-28.  А дальше правило на на  ъ.

Comment: *п.26. написано: "После согласных буква й не пишется". И дана ссылка на п.27-28.* - ))))  "На сарае тоже написано" (с). А что написано в "п.27" не судьба прочитать? Перед тем как ссылку давать?

Comment: *Ну а Серж эту ошибку просто скопипастил.* - так не признается же))) Но вообще-то, наверное да. Общими усилия диагноз поставлен. Вот только насчет правила действительно напряженно. Правила как такового нет. А посему и разбирать тут нечего.

Comment: Перед тем как дать ссылку, я читал п.27-28. Вот поэтому и спросил.